# Is the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x_1|}}$integrable on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, singular-integrals

Is the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x_1|}}$integrable on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$? That is, is the integral
$$\int_{S^{n-1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x_1|}}d\sigma(x)$$
finite? Where $\sigma$ means the volume measure on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, which is the same as the $n-1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure on $S^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S^d_r$ denote the $d$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$, and let $x=(x_1,\bar x)$ with $\bar x=(x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and let $p>\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
\int_{S^{n-1}}\frac{1}{|x_1|^p}\,d\sigma(x)=\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{|x_1|^p}\int_{S^{n-2}_{\sqrt{1-|x_1|^2}}}d\sigma(\bar x)\,dx_1=\omega_n\int_{-1}^1\frac{(1-|x_1|^2)^{(n-2)/2}}{|x_1|^p}\,dx_1,
$$
where $\omega_n$ is the surface area of the unit $n-2$-dimensional sphere. The last integral is convergent if $p<1$.

Comment: So you mean there is the relation of measures: $d\sigma (x_{1}, \bar{x})=dx_{1}d\sigma (\bar{x})$? How can I deduce this relation? Can you explain or give some reference?

Comment: You can think of it as a polar change of coordinates. For each $z\in[-1,1]$, the intersection of $S^{n-1}$ with the hyperplane $x_1=z$ is an $n-2$-dimensional sphere of radius $\sqrt{1-|z|^2}$.